# Does my wallet software need to be running to get Ether payments?

Tags: mist, wallets

I was wondering what happens if someone made a payment to me whilst my wallet software (for example Mist) was **not** running on my computer?

Will the payment be lost or will it show once I start the software?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can receive payments without your wallet software running.  (It's like you can receive email without being logged in to your email software.)  Once your wallet is started and synchronized (synced) with the network, you will see the payment.